# Glassfish logs to a null Logger - how to set the log level then?

Tags: jakarta-ee, null, java.util.logging

I'm coding on GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5) with Netbeans7.3.
I use java.util.Logging and changed the Logging format of the console - no change to the glassfish logs. When I set the root Logger level to Level.ALL, and then fine tune the level on a package or class basis, I am stuck with a large volume of messages that are sent by various getJNDIName methods from com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl.

The problem is that they appear to be send to a null Logger, which obviously I cannot access to set it to a quieter level.

I tried to access the Logger using a non null String, "null", but that won't do either :)

This is my customFormatter :

```
public class CustomFormatter extends Formatter {

@Override
public String format(LogRecord record) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(record.getLevel());
    sb.append(":");
    sb.append(record.getLoggerName());
    sb.append("\t[");
    sb.append(record.getSourceMethodName());
    sb.append(" @ ");
    sb.append(record.getSourceClassName());
    sb.append("] ");        
    sb.append(new Date(record.getMillis()).toString());        
    sb.append("\n\t\t ");
    sb.append(formatMessage(record));
    sb.append("\n");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I configure it this way, inside a @Startup @Singleton EJB :

```
protected static void configureLogger() {
    try {
        Logger.getLogger(StartUpSingleton.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Preparing to configure Logger");
        Handler hh[] = Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers();

        Logger.getLogger(StartUpSingleton.class.getCanonicalName()).log(Level.INFO, "There are {0} available handlers", hh.length);
        for (Handler hf : hh) {
            Logger.getLogger(StartUpSingleton.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Handler found : {0}", hf.toString());
            if (java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.class.isInstance(hf)) {
                hf.setFormatter(new CustomFormatter());
                CustomLogLevel.configure(hf);
            }

        }


        Logger.getLogger(StartUpSingleton.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Done with  configure Logger");

    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StartUpSingleton.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
}
```

Using the following configuration object where I set all the details levels I want:

```
class CustomLogLevel {

static void configure(Handler hf) {

    hf.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    Logger.getLogger("").setLevel(Level.ALL);
    // Logger.getLogger(null).setLevel(Level.INFO) is impossible !
    Logger.getLogger("null").setLevel(Level.INFO); // I tried ... ;-)
    Logger.getLogger("com.sun").setLevel(Level.INFO);
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.INFO);
    Logger.getLogger("grizzly").setLevel(Level.INFO);
    Logger.getLogger("global").setLevel(Level.INFO);
    Logger.getLogger("sun").setLevel(Level.INFO);
    Logger.getLogger("LogStrings").setLevel(Level.INFO);

    Logger.getLogger("com.myprivate.package").setLevel(Level.ALL);
    // ...



}

}
```

And this is the log I get on the console, overflowed by FINE or FINER/FINEST events that  are not related to mine ( I want however to be able to see my own events of any level and thus, setting global level to info does not work for me ...)

```
FINEST:null [getJndiNameEnvironment @ com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl] Mon Apr 29 17:11:36 CEST 2013
     ComponentEnvManagerImpl: getJndiNameEnvironment 123ProductV1_/123ProductV1 is class com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebBundleDescriptor
FINEST:null [getJndiNameEnvironment @ com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl] Mon Apr 29 17:11:36 CEST 2013
     ComponentEnvManagerImpl: getJndiNameEnvironment 123ProductV1_/123ProductV1 is class com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebBundleDescriptor
FINEST:null [getCurrentJndiNameEnvironment @ com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl] Mon Apr 29 17:11:36 CEST 2013
     ComponentEnvManagerImpl: getCurrentJndiNameEnvironment 123ProductV1_/123ProductV1 is class com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebBundleDescriptor
FINEST:null [getJndiNameEnvironment @ com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl] Mon Apr 29 17:11:36 CEST 2013
     ComponentEnvManagerImpl: getJndiNameEnvironment 123ProductV1_/123ProductV1 is class com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebBundleDescriptor
FINEST:null [getCurrentJndiNameEnvironment @ com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl] Mon Apr 29 17:11:36 CEST 2013
     ComponentEnvManagerImpl: getCurrentJndiNameEnvironment 123ProductV1_/123ProductV1 is class com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebBundleDescriptor
FINEST:null [getJndiNameEnvironment @ com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl] Mon Apr 29 17:11:36 CEST 2013
     ComponentEnvManagerImpl: getJndiNameEnvironment 123ProductV1_/123ProductV1 is class com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebBundleDescriptor
FINEST:null [getCurrentJndiNameEnvironment @ com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl] Mon Apr 29 17:11:36 CEST 2013
     ComponentEnvManagerImpl: getCurrentJndiNameEnvironment 123ProductV1_/123ProductV1 is class com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebBundleDescriptor
FINEST:null [getJndiNameEnvironment @ com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl] Mon Apr 29 17:11:36 CEST 2013
     ComponentEnvManagerImpl: getJndiNameEnvironment 123ProductV1_/123ProductV1 is class com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebBundleDescriptor
FINEST:null [getJndiNameEnvironment @ com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl] Mon Apr 29 17:11:36 CEST 2013
     ComponentEnvManagerImpl: getJndiNameEnvironment 123ProductV1_/123ProductV1 is class com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebBundleDescriptor
FINEST:null [getCurrentJndiNameEnvironment @ com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl] Mon Apr 29 17:11:36 CEST 2013
     ComponentEnvManagerImpl: getCurrentJndiNameEnvironment 123ProductV1_/123ProductV1 is class com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebBundleDescriptor
FINEST:null [getJndiNameEnvironment @ com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl] Mon Apr 29 17:11:36 CEST 2013
... / ...
```

Any suggestions on how to neutralize the log flooding (without xml configuration) ?

Xavier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - This is apparently not a bug ( are these AnonymousLogger ?), since various other packages are creating Log messages with a null name. I decided to workaround the issue by using the formatter to filter these out :

```
@Override
public String format(LogRecord record) {
    if(record.getLoggerName() == null) {
          return ;
          }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(record.getLevel());
    sb.append(":");
    .../...
```

It works perfectly well, allowing to have my customized console view, without modifying any of the server or file configurations ...